# Does using a push only plug for and F connector in a coaxial cable decreases the signal or adds noise?

Tags: signal-integrity, coax, wire-terminals

I'm intending to find a replacement cable for my cablemodem unit. The existing cable that the phone company installed is a screw in terminal on both ends of the coaxial cable with one end connected to the modem and the other connected to a splitter.

What I intend to do is to replace the cable with another one which has a non screw F terminal, something which can be plugged by only pressing it against the female terminal either the modem or the splitter.

Upon browsing online [I found these](https://www.parts-express.com/f-connector-screw-on-to-push-on-adapter--090-357) and also [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UEL9EOI).

The reason for why I intend to use these instead of the regular screw in type F connector is because my cablemodem is in a temporary place (as I have recently moved) and I have to disconnect it from time to time to take the unit to other part of the house.

And I noticed after unplugging it a couple of times the screw indents on the edges of the female and male terminals seem to be wearing off. In order to avoid further worsening the situation (other than obviously finding for them a more permanent place, which I cannot do for the time being) I considered to use these friendly pushing in alternatives for a type F connector.

However, **neither of these indicate if the signal will be affected by using this?**. Will it make any noticeable difference?. Back in the 90s my tv cable provider installed the cable to a wall in my house and I noticed the socket in the wall had much noise, so when I replaced the F terminal and connected it directly to the tv it improved a lot the quality of the image, hence my question.

I do not have an oscilloscope neither any other sophisticated equipment to verify this. But does it exist any reason to believe such?

Has anyone used these cables?. I remember using them on my VCR equipment back in the 90s as well and I had good experience using these push only F terminals, never had any sort of diminishing the quality. But since I intend to use these for a cablemodem which transfers data, will that make any difference?. If I buy the cable on amazon which I had referenced earlier will it be a safe choice?. Does the influx of information on a coaxial cable will it make it get hot or something? Does it exist better alternatives along the options which I have mentioned above?.

AS mentioned I also [found this](https://www.showmecables.com/rg59-push-on-f-type-coax-cable) but I have no idea if it will be safe, does it exist some specification or some group of cables which say specifically **only for tv use** or **not for internet use**. **Does it exist some standard for this?** **Can someone guide me with this matter?**.

Comment: Never having tried one I would expect them to be suitable for your application if they make a snug connection.  If they are loose and rattle then you will have random signal problems. If you have a simple multimeter you can check the continuity of the connection by checking the resistance between the socket and the connector when mated.  Compare with a screw type, both should easily be below 1 Ohm.

Comment: @KalleMP It would be nice if an answer would show up. I wish I could do the same with the cablemodem but once the connectors are mated there isn't really a way to plug in the multimeter outside the unit other than just placing the needle probes over the male and female in both connectors, but that really doesn't provide much accuracy to my previous experience doing this. Although the method could be used in a wall socket.